nginx proxy manager. - custom locations setting for the proxy host
I have a React app that I want to host under example.com/app.
I spin up Nginx proxy manager and create a proxy host for the main landing static page, then use this host to create custom locations:

then I use Docker to create a container to host my React app with config:
server{
   listen 80;
   server_name _;
   
   location / {
      root /var/www/htm;
      index index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
}

of course the Docker I will forward the port 8880->80tcp.
I can test see my site in xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8880 no problem,
but when I go to https://example.com/app, I will get:
403 Forbidden
nginx/1.27.1

Where did I go wrong?

i think you setup is completely diffrent for react app running in docker and the nginx that you are setting up.
if you application is running in docker and can be accessible in  xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8880
then you need to proxy pass the container port in nginx as follows:
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name _;

   location /app/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  # Assuming your React app is running on port 3000 inside the container
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
}

on top of that if you want to access it in the domain http://example.com/app then is additional config as follows:
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;

   location /app/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  # Assuming your React app is running on port 3000 inside the container
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
}

and set the host ip to hosting the container to A record of example.com in dns settings
lastly if you want to access your domain with ssl like this https://example.com/app , then you need to apply your own ssl or you can use certbot:
when using cerbot your nginx will be as follows:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    location /app/ {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    # SSL Configuration
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /app/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  # Adjust based on where your React app is running
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Ensuring that the React app handles all client-side routing
        try_files $uri /app/index.html;
    }
}


please check the cerbot link for implementing certbot, its for nginx in ubuntu 20.04 but you can get other setup if you search it in stackoverflow or browse google.
